Discord Python bot RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.run.<locals>.runner' was never awaited
I had a discord bot with several extensions that worked well. I left it for several months and now it doesn't work
I have this error and don't know how to solve it:
"...raise errors.ExtensionFailed(key, e) from e
discord.ext.commands.errors.ExtensionFailed: Extension 'change' raised an error: RuntimeError: asyncio.run()
cannot be called from a running event loop
sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.run..runner' was never awaited"
I tried following a guide and now I have this in my main file:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import mysql.connector


#connections with databases...


class CustomBot(commands.Bot):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(
            command_prefix="gg",
            intents=discord.Intents.all()
        )

    async def setup_hook(self):
        await self.load_extension("change")

CustomBot().run("mytoken")

and something like this in one of my extensions:
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from ggbot import conexion_inventarios, conexion_juegos, tablas_suffix


#connections with databases


class MiComandoCog1(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    

    @commands.command()
    async def emoji(self, ctx, emoji: discord.Emoji):
        await ctx.send(f":{emoji.name}:{emoji.id}")


    @commands.command()
    async def change(self, ctx, columna_a_cambiar, nombre_encontrar, valor):
        for sufijo in tablas_suffix:
            cursor_juegos.execute(f"SELECT {columna_a_cambiar} FROM per_{sufijo} WHERE nombres = '{nombre_encontrar}'")
            resultado = cursor_juegos.fetchone()
        
            if resultado is not None:
                cursor_juegos.execute(f"UPDATE per_{sufijo} SET {columna_a_cambiar} = '{valor}' WHERE nombres = '{nombre_encontrar}'")
                conexion_juegos.commit()
        await ctx.send("Valores cambiados.")


    # more commands...
        

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.guild and message.guild.me.guild_permissions.ban_members:
            await message.author.ban(reason="no speek")
        
    async def cog_load(self):
        print(f"{self.__class__.__name__} loaded!")

    async def cog_unload(self):
        print(f"{self.__class__.__name__} unloaded!")    

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(MiComandoCog1(bot=bot))`


The error message RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Client.run.<locals>.runner' was never awaited typically arises when you attempt to run your Discord bot outside of an asynchronous context. This is because the setup_hook function, which is asynchronous, cannot be used outside of such a context.
To fix this issue, it would be best to start the bot within an asynchronous context:
.. your code ..


# Login to Discord
bot = CustomBot()
async def login() -> None:
    async with bot:
        await bot.start("token")


# Don't run the login twice
if __name__ == "__main__":
    done = asyncio.run(login())

You should also make sure that your Cog file is named change and should be located in the same folder as your main file - otherwise he can't find the extension.
By the way: Discord.py offers many simple examples how to use the library on their Github Repo: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/examples

Okay!
And how can I load the extensions in addition to fixing the login? (there are several)

That is another question.
